# linux ./configure, make and make install commands

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux, I know that to install any package or software we have to do this steps but I would to know in detail about it like how it works and what are all the parameter are there with these commands. 
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You can read up abotu autoconf here https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/

Comment: Try apt-get (or your distribution's equivalent).

Comment: And you should also read up on [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: You may check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529566/what-does-a-typical-configure-do-in-linux

Comment: configure script
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script

Answer (score 0):

Usually to build and install an application from the source code, it's `./configure` followed by `make`, followed by `sudo make install`.

If you just want to install an application, let's say `git` (for example), use `sudo apt-get install git` or `sudo yum install git`... depends on what your distribution's package manager is.

Comment: What about the flag used with the make file